# Passing a value from one Button to other in qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to pass a **QFile** datatype "input_file" from **on_pushButton_clicked** to **on_pushButton_2_clicked**.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString filepath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
          this,
          "Open Document",
          QDir::currentPath(),
          "All files (*.*) ;; Document files (*.doc *.rtf);; PNG files (*.png)");

    QFile input_file(filepath);
    if(!input_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        QMessageBox::information(0,"info",input_file.errorString());

    ui->textBrowser->setText(input_file);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QTextStream input_text_stream(&input_file);

}
```

Any help regarding this will be appriciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define input_file as a member of MainWindow.  As is you would be passing a reference to a stack variable.  As soon as that variable goes out of scope the reference would be invalid.  Making input_file a member of MainWindow gives both functions access to that file handle.

```
class MainWindow {
   ...
private:
   QFile input_file;
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make input_file a field of MainWindow.